# Confused about CWnd::OnLButtonDown() and CTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown()

Tags: c++, mfc

MFC Library Reference
CWnd::OnLButtonDown

```
void CMyCla::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CMyTreeCla::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

I know the inheritance.

```
class CTreeCtrl : public CWnd
{
......
}
```

Is there any clear rule to follow when i want to call OnLButtonDown()?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you prehaps make it a little clearer what your question is? Would you like to know how to handle a OnLButtonDown message for your CMyTreeClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want.

In your class header, you will need to declare the message map, and also write the function header.

```
Class myCWnd : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() //note, no semi colon

    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown( UINT nFlags, CPoint pt );
};
```

in the cpp file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(myCWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void myCWnd::OnLButtonDown( UINT nFlags, CPoint pt )
{
    //do what you want here

    CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, pt); //call base class method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parent class implementation to be called first then you call the parent class's OnLButtonDown() and then add your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you do what you want to do with the event in your implementation and then you call the implementation of the parent class. [This codeguru post](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c723/) shows a nice example in step 2 of the tutorial. But this depends on what exactly you want to do with the OnLButtonDown event, so it might be the other way around in your case.

I assume the inheritance in your example is as follows:

```
class CMyCla : public CWnd
{
}

class CMyTreeCla : public CTreeCtrl
{
......
}
```

So indeed, as you do, you do your thing in either OnLButtonDown and then call the parent implementation:

```
void CMyCla::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // Your stuff here
    // blah
    // end your stuff
    CWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CMyTreeCla::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // Your stuff here
    // blah
    // end your stuff
    CTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```